# Application Loader Error - IOS Upload

Tags: ios4, app-store, xcode4, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload a binary using Application Loader 1.3.  I am receiving the following error.  I have recently upgraded to XCode 4.

com.apple.transporter.util.StreamUtil.readBytes(Ljava/io/InputStream;)[B

Any thoughts?

Comment: We are having the same issue, also with App Loader 1.4.1 and with XCode 4 via Organizer -> Archives. Some people are talking about this problem here:

http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=13205902#13205902

We also wrote to the iTunes Connect team, but have no answer yet :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks J,

I have fixed the issue by uninstalling Xcode 4 and the SDK

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

Then reinstalling Xcode 3 with the 4.3 SDK using  https://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20792

I will wait until XCode 4 is a little more mature.  I believe the issue may be related to the version of the Java runtime on the machine I am using.  If you check the error logs then there is an issue with the loader doing some reflection.

Comment: The same thing worked for me, except I reinstalled Xcode 4 (not 3) and it worked after that.

Answer (score 10):

i can confirm that

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

and reinstalling xcode 401 + SDK4.3 gets rid of the transporter.util error

Comment: I had the same error trying to submit after upgrading to XCode 4.0.2. I had to remove the devtools (as above) and then re-install XCode 4.0.2, and then submit worked fine -- no need to downgrade, but you do need to uninstall first. (I suspect the problem is something that is missed in the upgrade but works fine with a clean install.)

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue with App Loader 1.4.1
Downgrading to 1.3 (http://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_1.3.dmg) solved it.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to first remove/rename the 1.4 version in /Developer/Applications/Utilities.

Comment: I've got App Loader 1.3 running but it won't take the .xcarchive file that was built by Xcode 4.0.1 .  Do I need to generate a different kind of file to use it?

Comment: Downgrading to 1.3 didn't work for me, but it did give me the idea to find a different version of Application Loader that would work.  See my answer if this doesn't work.

Comment: this didn't work for me, app submitted in organizer(which seems bogus), but won't show up in itunes.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue for submitting to the Mac App Store with Xcode 3.2.6.  I had Xcode 4 installed, but only on a separate partition.

I didn't want to uninstall and reinstall all of the developer tools, so I tried the other suggested answer above, which was to downgrade to Application Loader 1.3.  Sadly, this didn't work either, because when I tried to validate or submit to the Mac App Store, Xcode would claim that I had not marked the application in iTunes Connect as "Ready for Upload".  I double- and triple-checked in Xcode that I had already marked the application as such (and Application Loader 1.4.1 had no problems with that).

So, instead, I tried finding a different version of Application Loader that might work.   With Pacifist ( http://www.charlessoft.com/ ), I extracted Application Loader 1.4.1 from the Xcode 4.1 DP1 installer (that I had saved).  When replacing the existing Application Loader (also version 1.4.1) that came with Xcode 3.2.6, the version from Xcode 4.1 DP1 did not have the "com.apple.transporter.util.StreamUtil.readBytes(Ljava/io/InputStream;)[B" problem as mentioned in the question.

So that's another alternative to try.  This fix has been confirmed by another developer.

In case you don't have a copy of the Xcode 4.1 DP1 installer, you can download just that version of Application Loader by going here: https://public.me.com/ix/simx/Application-Loader-1.4.1-from-Xcode-4.1-dp1.zip

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and a few others. Uninstalled using sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all then reinstalled Xcode 4 & SDK which cleared up any issues. App uploaded without a hitch.